# Mapping a parameter tibble on to the function assign with pmap produces a list, not objects in the environment (as desired)

Tags: r, assign, purrr, pmap

Preamble: [A related SO question that I tried to emulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075407/assigning-pmap-output-to-dataframes-with-pattern-names), but received the same (incorrect) result.

I'm trying to pass a tibble of parameters to `assign` via `purrr::pmap`. My parameter `tibble` has two columns: the name (`chr`), and the data (`tbl_df`). A small, reproducible example:

```
x <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

value <- list(
  mtcars,
  iris,
  rock
)

params <- tibble(x = x, value = value)

pmap(params, assign)
```

The output is just a list of the dataframes (mtcars, iris, rock), but **no objects ("One", "Two", "Three") are created in the environment (as desired)**. I have tried `map2`, along the lines of the SO post mentioned above:

```
map2(.x = x, .y = value, .f = ~ assign(.x, .y))
```

... which gives the same undesired output (a list of dataframes).

TIA

## Benchmarking results from answers

I was curious as to how to these functions would perform. The only difference here is to save computation, I create a tibble of the named dataframes, then apply `get` Here's my code using `rbenchmark`:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark( 

  map2 = {
    x <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

    value <- list(
      "mtcars",
      "iris",
      "rock"
    )

    purrr::map2(.x = x, .y = value, .f = ~ assign(.x, get(.y), envir = .GlobalEnv))
  },

  walk2 = {
    x <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

    value <- list(
      "mtcars",
      "iris",
      "rock"
    )

    purrr::walk2(.x = x, .y = value, .f = ~ assign(.x, get(.y), envir = .GlobalEnv))
  },

  list2env = {
    x <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

    value <- list(
      "mtcars",
      "iris",
      "rock"
    )

    list2env(setNames(lapply(value, get), x), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  },
  replications = 10000,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
              "relative", "user.self", "sys.self")
)
```

Result:

```
      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
3 list2env        10000    0.14      1.0      0.14     0.00
1     map2        10000    1.05      7.5      0.91     0.02
2    walk2        10000    4.20     30.0      4.20     0.00
```

Comment: Desired output is: `r` objects `One`, `Two`, `Three` (in original question - bolded now in question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option in `base R` would be to extract the `list` column into a named `list` and use `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(params$value, params$x), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I added the benchmarking results in my question for `map2`, `walk2`, and `list2env`. Your answer was the fastest with 0.14s, then `map2` with 1.05s, and `walk2` 4.20s. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please add `envir = .GlobalEnv` to your `assign` in the `map2` call. In addition, in this case, `map2` would print out a list. If you don't like that, you can use `walk2` as follows.

```
walk2(.x = x, .y = value, .f = ~ assign(.x, .y, envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! `map2(.x = x, .y = value, .f = ~ assign(.x, .y, envir = .GlobalEnv))`